# Python - Convert a list of strings to multiple lists

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list such as:

```
cols = ['price', 'cost', 'buy', 'sell']
```

Now, I'd like to iterate through `cols` and create lists names after each item, i.e.:

```
price = []
cost = []
buy = []
sell = []
```

Tried:

```
for col in cols:
    cols[col] = []
```

But this obviously fails.

Which would be the most pythonic way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: see the dupe - slightly different context but same idea: `for var in cols: locals()[var] = []`

Comment: Slightly different as I don't want a list of lists, but rather each element in the original list to be named after the string.

Comment: Read my answer in the dupe and my above comment again. There is no list of lists anywhere

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/HideousSpryCommunication   you can try a default dict whose key is the name of your original list and whose value is an empty list.